# difference between getc and fscanf

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, getc

why does the following code work fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     FILE *fp=fopen("input.txt","r+");
     char c;
     while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
     {
         printf("%c",c);
     }
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

but this code gives an error 'segmentation fault, core dumped':

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     FILE *fp=fopen("input.txt","r+");
     char c;
     while((c=fscanf(fp,"%c",&c))!=EOF)
     {
         printf("%c",c);
     }
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

input.txt contains a space separated list of characters like: a b c d e f

Comment: `c` should be `int` - you can have an infinite loop if the target platform uses unsigned chars, because `c` will always be converted to a positive `int` (again, only in platforms with unsigned chars), and thus will never be equal to `EOF`

Comment: It will not work correctly, but I think it so as not to cause a segment fault.

Comment: I'm not sure of what is meant by target platform but I'm running this program on ubuntu terminal

Comment: @codeln See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform

Comment: Probably File is not be opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work the way you expect:

```
while((c=fscanf(fp,"%c",&c))!=EOF)
```

`getc()` returns the character read, which can be `EOF`, but `fscanf()` returns the number of input items assigned, or `EOF` if there was a failure before any conversion took place.

You can't assign this return value to `c`, because the return value is not the character read (which you then try to print later).

You should try this instead:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) == 1)
```

Or:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) != EOF)
```

Which is equivalent to saying "As long as there is a character to read..."

Also, in the first case (the code where you use `getc()`), `c` should be int - you can have an infinite loop if the target platform uses unsigned chars, because `c` will always be converted to a positive int (again, only in platforms with unsigned chars), and thus will never be equal to `EOF`. If you check the manpages for `getc()` and `putc()` (and other functions that deal with a character), you will see that they receive `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are absolutely right. Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, your answer was very helpful. Is there any other difference between getc and fscanf that I should keep in mind?

Comment: @codeln Well, `fscanf()` is way more powerful than `getc()`. `getc()` reads character by character, `fscanf()` gives you all the power of formatting specifiers.